# Dictionary dynamic vs object and reference

Tags: c#

I have my own data types for use with a database that have various properties to manipulate values such as:

```
First: original value
IsNull: is the current state null (no value in Data)
IsFirstNull: was the initial state of the object null
Changed: has the value changed since the initial value was set.
SetNull(): set the object to null
SetFirstNull: set the initial value to null
Reset: set values all to original settings.
```

Each one of the objects has these. There is an object for each type of standard variables, such as:

```
int - IntType
string - StringType
bool - BoolType
```

I have these variables in a class for each table I am using.

I want to be able to access these, so I am looking at adding these to a dictionary.  But each item would be a different type (IntType, StringType, BoolType etc).

So I set these up as `Dictionary<string, object>` or as `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`.

Not sure which is the best - Is one better than the other?

```
 public class LoginDC
 {
    private IntType loginID = new IntType();
    private StringType userName = new StringType();

    public LoginDC()
    {
       Dictionary<string, dynamic> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

       propertyList.Add("LoginID", loginID);
       propertyList.Add("UserName", userName);

       propertyList["UserName"].First = "Tom"
    }
 }
```

So my other question is:

Does propertyList contain the reference to loginID and userName after the .Add?  So that if I change either the propertyList or the variable both would contain the same value.  Or does propertyList contain a copy of the value in the two variables?

It seems to be a reference but not sure.

Comment: `I have my own data types for use with a database` - Dude, you're trying to reinvent the wheel. Use an ORM instead. Also, how does your `IsNull()` deal with non-nullable (value) types such as `int` .. ?

Comment: No, LoginID will contain what you Add, and if you change LoginID, the element in the `propertyList` will remain without changes

Comment: This kind of looks like the guts of [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive).

Comment: I agree that this is trying to duplicate work done by others.  Try an ORM.  Massive by Rob Conery is nice!

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, but between them `object` is better. And even better is to have a base class (or interface) for your *types* and use that instead of `object` or `dynamic`.

Comment: I am a little confused on AnnArbors answer.  The answer below says that the loginID will change if you change it in propertyList (I assume vice versa).  But AnnArbor seems to say that it won't change.

Comment: Actually, I don't have a base class.  What I have is an abstract class DataType<T>.  I can't use that as my type in the Dictionary object.

Answer (score 2):

Both `Dictionary<string, object>` and `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` have their down-sides. Using `object`, you'd have to cast each object to its type before you could use it. Using `dynamic`, you'd lose compile-time checks on the methods you call, increasing the likelihood of having errors that you don't notice until it's too late.

I wouldn't suggest taking the approach you're taking at all. The commenters are right: you appear to be trying to reinvent the wheel. There are lots of really good libraries for mapping data from a database into objects. Use what's freely available.

To answer your second question:

- If your custom object types are `class`es, then `propertyList` contains references to them.
- If they are `struct`s, it will contain a copy of them.

You can test this yourself by running a quick script like this in a tool like LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new A{I = 1};
    var b = new B{I = 1};
    var propertyList = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    propertyList.Add("a", a);
    propertyList.Add("b", b);
    a.I = 2;
    b.I = 2;
    foreach (var value in propertyList.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value.I);
    }
    // Output:
    //  2
    //  1
}

public class A{public int I{get;set;}}
public struct B{public int I{get;set;}}
```

Comment: I understand about other libraries.  This is code I had from years ago and am just updating it as well as looking at different techniques.  If I changed my original Dictionary line from dynamic to object - how would I change the line:

propertyList["UserName"].First = "Tom"

This doesn't work with object - how would I cast it without knowing what the object is?  Obviously, with dynamic - I don't need to know.  Which is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: `((StringType)propertyList["UserName"]).First = "Tom"`

Comment: Actually that wouldn't work since the way I am going to use this is to pass the string name in (username). So I wouldn't know the type.  In the watch window, propertyList2["userName"] returns {DataLayer.StringType}.  So I tried: ((propertyList2["userName"])propertyList2["userName"]).First, but that gave me an error saying ") expected, not sure why.  So actually, dynamic may be better since it knows the type and I don't have to give it.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2462093: If you don't know that `propertyList["UserName"]` is a `StringType`, what do you know? If you know that it has a `First` property that is a `string`, then you should be able to define an interface for that, and cast the object to that interface. If you know that it has a `First` property, but you don't know what type that property has, then how do you know you can assign "Tom" to it?

Comment: But I don't know what it is.  It could also be propertyList["LoginId"] which is an IntType.  The key would be passed in so I don't know what the type is.  The actual use for this particular dictionary in my code is to set the values to null.  So a SetNull function would be called that passed in the key (which is from an enum so there is no chance for an error) and then something like this would be called:  propertyList[keyName].SetFirstNull().  So like the other example, it still needs a type.  I tried this as well, which didn't work:  propertyList["UserName"].GetType().